# How to determine the number of rows returned from MYSQL select

Tags: mysql

I want to add a progress bar to my program.

Is it possible to read the number of rows that a select command is going to return before the data is sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to determine how long a statement will take to process. If you want to know how many datasets a statement will return you will need to execute the statement to know.

Answer (score 1):

No. You would have to do something like this before

```
select count(*) from your_table where ...
```

and afterwards the real query

```
select col1, col2 from your_table where ...
```

The reason is that the DB engine does not know how many records it will return until it applies the query and searches the data.

Comment: I thought that would be the case. Wouldn't it cause a problem if another process updated the table in between?

Comment: You could lock the table if you need to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think Only way you can do is fire two queries
 one with

```
select count(*) .....
```

and the other one is with

```
select * from ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(*) from `table` where <condition>.
```

MySql wouldn't know what to count if you don't specify what you're looking for.